# Portfolio lazy load not working properly in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress i developed one theme heaving one portfolio section i applied lazy load.
i am facing problem with images not shown in proper manner(proper size).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTMPV.jpg)

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item <?php echo strtolower($tax); ?>">
      <div class="portfolio-wrap">
        <img src="<?php the_field('image_loader', 'option'); ?>" data-echo="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="img-fluid " alt="">
        <div class="portfolio-info">
          <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
          <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 1" class="link-preview" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
            <a href=<?php the_permalink() ?> class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

js file name echo.min.js
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DHLLdv3CTEmukndqy8f-EUln6uYddcYy

reference youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUz6KYREkWM&t=654s

Comment: If you just disable the lazy load instantiation, do they then load properly?  Also, can you provide whatever errors you're getting in your console as well as perhaps the relevant code to this page?